# PostgreSQL cast array to two-dimensional

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array, casting

I am new at `PostgreSQL`, I use `array` type in `PostgreSQL`

```
WITH intarr AS (
    SELECT
        ARRAY [ s.days,s.hours ] ::int[] AS arr
    FROM summary s
    WHERE s.hours != 2
)
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT * from intarr );
```

I get this error:

> [Err] ERROR:  could not find array type for data type integer[]

I find a way change

```
ARRAY [ s.days,s.hours ] ::int[] AS arr
```

row to this

```
ARRAY [ s.days,s.hours ] ::varchar AS arr
```

I get result like : `{"{1,3}","{2,3}"}` . But I need result `int[][]` type .How I convert `one-dimensional array` to `two-dimensional array`

Comment: I did it, but I don't know is it good solution ? 

`SELECT replace( (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT arr from intarr)::VARCHAR), '"', '')::int[][]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use it for now,I don't think it is perfect way.

```
WITH intarr AS (
    SELECT
        ARRAY [ s.days,s.hours ] ::VARCHAR AS arr
    FROM
        summary s
    WHERE
        s.hours != 2
)
SELECT replace((SELECT ARRAY(SELECT arr from intarr)::VARCHAR), '"', '')::int[][]
```